# How can I get multiple progress bars with different ID's on the same line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap progress bar that displays a user's proficiency (basically, correct responses over attempts). However, I'd like to colorize the difference with two bars, one labeled "bg-success" and another labeled "bg-warning", to make the contrast more apparent. I did this with progress bars with different ID's. The problem is that the progress bars won't appear on the same line.

The code below shows where I'm at, and I've tried every relabeling attempt I could to repair it, to no avail.

Here's the relevant JavaScript:

```
function setBars() {
  var profPerc = Number(((myProg[1] / myProg[2]) * 100).toFixed(csvSize.toString().length));
  document.getElementById("profBar").innerHTML = "<strong>" + profPerc.toString() + "</strong>";
  document.getElementById("profBar").style.width = profPerc + "%";
  document.getElementById("offBar").innerHTML = "<strong>&nbsp;</strong>";
  document.getElementById("offBar").style.width = (100 - profPerc) + "%";
}

// There are no errors with any of the other above-mentioned variables.
```

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="proficiencydiv">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" id="profBar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" id="offBar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

I expect a result that looks like this:

```
"[profBar][offBar]".
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
"[profBar]"

"[offBar]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added below css

```
.proficiencydiv{
    display: flex}
```

```css
.proficiencydiv{
display: flex}

.proficiencydiv div{
margin: 10px}
```

```html
<div class="proficiencydiv">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" id="profBar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">profBar</div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" id="offBar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">offBar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the "display: flex;" into the proficiencydiv style value, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!